# how to set cmd line args in run through a line-per-line pipe to bash

Tags: bash

say that the only way to execute a bash script is like
"cat script.sh | bash" (in the real situation it is a
binary that writes its output line per line to an 
anonymous pipe with a bash instance connected to
its reading end)
Is there a way to pass cmdline args (ie make it act 
as it was run like  "bash script.sh a b c" so 
that $@ is not empty)?

thanks beforehand for any pointer
GK

Comment: Are you able to use `echo "script.sh" | bash`? Then you would just include parameters in the string. For example `echo "ls -l" | bash` works for me, producing `ls -l` output. What you have given would send each line of `script.sh` separately to bash.

Comment: yes Joe, that  is the idea: have a program gradually produce a full syntactically correct bash script and feed it to bash line-by line as each line gets generated. The problem is that the generated in-memory script does (and has to) refer to cmdline args

Answer (score 1):

ok, after some exotic tries in vain with BASH_ARGC/ARGV passed in execve's env array, I found the easy solution: cat script.sh | bash -s a b c